# Is there an R function for displaying variable labels?

Tags: r, label

I'm working with a national survey which has several variables named and labeled differently. To work with this survey I've always used STATA but now I'm trying to move to R. For example, this survey has a binary variable named `p02` which has a variable label of "sex", in STATA I can use the `describe` function that displays the name of the variable `p02` and the variable label "sex" and even the factor label like 1 for women and 0 for men.

How can I get that information in R, because R just shows me the variable name `p02`?

Comment: Are you looking for `str`?

Comment: I have used `str` but just shows me the variable type and lenght.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` you could one of the following:

```
str(df$p02) #shows the structure of the variable

unique(df$p02) #shows unique values of the variable
```